# Iterating through a string character by character in a loop

Tags: python, string, zelle-graphics

So I'm using the graphics module from Zelle in Python 3 and I'm trying to make it so the user inputs a word and then every time they click in a graphics window, it draws the next letter of the word where I click. I know this has to use string indexing, but I'm unsure how to iterate through the string indexes as parsing the loop's variable into the index gives the error that string indices must be integers.

```
word_input = input("Enter a word!")
win = GraphWin("Graphic Letters", 400,400)
for ch in word_input:
    click_location = win.getMouse()
    word_written = Text(click_location, word_input[1])
    word_written.draw(win)
```

This is what I have so far, but I can only parse numbers into

> word_input[]

as it won't let me put 'ch' in it to iterate through each of the string's indices. So if I put in 'bee' it'll only draw 'e' in the window three times where I click instead of drawing b, e, e in order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ch` is already the character, so you do no longer need to subscript `word_input`:

```
word_input = input("Enter a word!")
win = GraphWin("Graphic Letters", 400,400)
for ch in word_input:
    click_location = win.getMouse()
    word_written = Text(click_location, ch)
    word_written.draw(win)
```

A string is an iterable of its characters (which are strings as well), so if you write `for ch in word_input`, then `ch` will each iteration have as value the next character, for example:

```
>>> for ch in 'foobar':
...     print(ch)
... 
f
o
o
b
a
r
```

Note however that here it is likely that all characters will er rendered above each other. You might want to "sleep" between the iterations to give the user some time to move the mouse.

Comment: That's great, didn't realise it was that simple.Thanks!